# Add rows to datagridview dynamically

Tags: c#, datagridview

I usually don't post questions, and I know this answer is already out there somewhere but I'm not finding it for some reason.  Basically, I have a datagridview that has a variable number of columns, and variable number of rows.  So when I'm building it for the screen, I first add the columns using this code:

```
// Set column names
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
  fieldName = fromFileFields[i];
  dtaRecordDisplay.Columns.Add(fromFileFields[i}, fromFileFields[i});
}
```

Now, I would like to populate the rows in the view with something like this:

```
// Set row data
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
  dtaRecordDisplay.Rows.Add(Row1, Row2, etc., etc., etc..........);
}
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out the loop to be able to add all rows of data at once.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case I would fill a DataTable with columns and rows to work with, and bind that to the grid.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

// first add your columns
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    dt.Columns.Add(fromFileFields[i]);
}

// and then add your rows
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    var row = dt.NewRow();
    // Set values for columns with row[i] = xy
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
}

datagridview.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: The datagridview.DataSource needs to be set to dt.DefaultView, not the dt.

Comment: Thanks Marc. I believe that will work for me. It's opened a whole new can of worms, but it's a can I think I can muddle my way through!  I doubt I would have ever figured this one out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a `DataTable`, and bind that to your grid view. Then add the rows and colums to that, like Marc says:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35604744/5882760

The reason for that is, that the columns of the grid view instance only contain information on how to display the data from the attached `DataTable`.

They contain the information about what columbs to display, in what order, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code, you can add rows to dataGridViews without out any data Sources or data table.

```
dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
dtaGridView1 row = (DataGridViewRow)dataGridView1.Rows[0].Clone();
row.Cells[0].Value = "Your cell 0 Data";
row.Cells[1].Value = "Your cell 1 Data";
row.Cells[2].Value = "Your cell 2 Data";
   ………….
row.Cells[n].Value = "Your cell n Data";
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
```